# How to mathematically express and then optimize my photon emitter?

Tags: photons, inertia, optimization

A laser shoots photons directly at a flat disk with a fixed linear rate f(t) on the interval [t0=a,tn=b] with a horizontal path.

E.x. f(t)=100 photons per second

The laser is controlled by robotic motors that let's the laser choose any curve for its path from [a,b]

If the laser now follows a sin(t) curvature as it moves from left to right and the laser is shooting photons at a constant rate f(t) along the sin(t) path, is there instead a nonlinear photon firing rate that lets the laser move from [a,b] in a shorter time with less energy input?

I am imagining one solution with a photon firing rate of ln(t) gives a quick burst near t0 where the burst generates some amount of inertia that would create a 'most efficient solution' in terms of minimizing the energy required to move the laser and minimizing the time spent traveling from [a,b].

This might violent the law of energy conservation because I am not sure how, given p joules energy input and p+q joules is the output, where q comes from and is the 'free' energy gained (or not spent) from taking advantage of inertia.

Note: The laser is not in a fixed position and moves parallel to the flat disk.

If near $t_0$, wouldn't the photons be close together and generate more energy that could then internally power the rest of the body traveling along path $sin(t)$ $m/s$ and a firing rate of $ln(t)$ $photons/sec$?

Comment: I simply cannot understand your question. Can you define more notation and clearly state what every defined quantity is?